# Navbar Not Responding

Tags: html, css

I have a navbar on my webpage, I have also got information on my webpage. When I remove the information (paragraph and headings) the navbar functions perfectly. However when I place the information back, the navbar doesn't work whatsoever. Why does a website do this? Thanks.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2Ly9rbr7/) - With Information

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/megaL8ct/) - Without Information

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homepage.css">
  <title>CSGOMarble</title>
</head>
<body>  
<h3 style="float: right; margin-right: 25px;"><a href="http://www.steamcommunity.com/login/">SIGN IN WITH STEAM</a></h3>

<div class="logo">
  <img src="logo.png" alt="LOGO" height="60px" width="200px">
</div>

<hr>

<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li style="background-color: #D9D9D9; font-size: 20px; padding: 12px 0 12px 0;">MENU</li>
      <li><a href="coinflip.html">COINFLIP</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h2>CSGOMarble</h2>
  <u><h3 style="font-size: 20px; margin-right: 750px; margin-top: 75px;">What is CSGOMarble?</h3></u>
  <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-left: 478px; margin-right: 1000px; margin-top: 25px; text-align: justify;">CSGOMarble is a website which enables you to gamble your Counter-Strike skins so that you can try and turn a profit. We have many gamemodes, such as Coinflip, Roulette and Jackpot. Why not SIGN IN to test your luck?</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: white;
}
.logo {
margin-left: 25px;
}
.navbar {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 25px;
padding: 0;
font-size: 15px;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 175px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 2px solid #555;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}
li {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}

li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: This type of code is straightforward and normally works well. Did you check for missing braces or closing tags? What is the <hr> tag for, and does it have a closing tag?

Comment: you have given position:fixed for the container which is coming over the navbar. either remove position:fixed or use margin-top..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added position fixed to container , you can add z-index on both container and nav divs for fix this in your way as you want.

```
.navbar {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Change this Css Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `position:fixed` unless you want the element to NOT SCROLL with the page. This css settings is great for headers (navbars) that remain fixed to the screen/window and are always visible.

The other one that is similar to `position:fixed` is `position:absolute`, except that it will scroll up as the user scrolls down the page. However, both absolute and fixed allow you to use `top` `left` `right` `bottom` to precisely position the element on the screen. (One tip: the parent element must be either `position:absolute` or `position:relative` (relative is common).

Change `position:fixed` to `position:relative` for the `<div class="container">`